# Flutter offline data security

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

What is the best way to support offline download data security in a flutter app ? I checked a plugin [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) but the idea is not clear with this matter. Currently data is downloaded for offline purposes, in order to avoid (or at least make difficult) data access in other apps or extraction of data in anyway, what is the ideal method in flutter ?